# Show that $\pi_{n}(B)$ is isomorphic to $\pi_{n}(E)$.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, category-theory, covering-spaces, knot-theory

Let $(E, p, B)$ be a covering space with $B$ and $E$ both path-connected. Show that for all $n \geq 2,$  $\pi_{n}(B)$ is isomorphic to $\pi_{n}(E)$. Could anyone give me a hint for the solution please?

Comment: For a covering map $p:E\to B$ where $B$ and $E$ are path-connected, note that $p$ is a fibration with discrete fiber $F$.  (Path-connected of $B$ and $E$ is important; otherwise, $p$ might not be a fibration.)  For a discrete space $F$, $\pi_n(F)$ is trivial for every positive integer $n$.  Then you can use the same argument as in my answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3379347.

Comment: @WETutorialSchool could you please look at this question also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3379461/calculating-pi-1x/3379839?noredirect=1#comment6954756_3379839

Comment: In regard to your fist comment ..... will I use that theorem that "If $0 \rightarrow A \rightarrow B \rightarrow 0$  is exact with a map$ h: A \rightarrow  B$, then $h$ is an isomorphim "@WETutorialSchool

Comment: Yes, that is exactly why $\pi_n(E)\cong \pi_n(B)$ for $n>1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Lifting property of covering spaces.

Comment: where can I find a good explanation for it?

Comment: It's usually proved in any introduction to covering spaces. See proposition 1.30 in Hatcher's book.

Comment: And how can we relate it to long exact sequences? Do you have a reference for this?

Comment: You don't need to worry about the long exact sequence. Your statement is literally a consequence of the lifting property. Look it up.

Comment: My professor said that the proof includes using long exact sequences ... but I can not see why?

Comment: You need the homotopy lifting property to use the long exact sequence, so using the sequence feels backwards. Still, if you insist: The long exact sequence involves homotopy groups of three spaces, $B$, $E$ and $F$. Show that most of the groups of $F$ are trivial.

Comment: How do I need the homotopy lifting property to use the long exact sequence?

Comment: Is the question I am asking is proposition 4.1 in Hatcher?